# Get world space Oriented Boundin Box 8 points in unreal (C++)

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Does anybody know how to retrieve an actor's world space oriented bounding box 8 points in C++. Im reading the official documentation but it's a bit vague as it never specifies whether the bounds objects (FBox, FBoxShpereBounds) are local space, world space, axis aligned etc

I'm thinking something like below but I'm not sure if that's right

```
    UStaticMeshComponent* pMesh = Cast<UStaticMeshComponent>(actor->GetComponentByClass(UStaticMeshComponent::StaticClass()));
        if (pMesh)
        {
            UStaticMesh* pStaticMesh = pMesh->GetStaticMesh();
    
            if (pStaticMesh && pStaticMesh->GetRenderData())
            {
                FStaticMeshRenderData* pRenderData = pStaticMesh->GetRenderData();
                if (pRenderData)
                FBoxSphereBounds bounds = pRenderData->Bounds;
bounds.TransformBy(actor>GetActorTransform());
    
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unreal maintains it's bounds as axis-aligned (AABB).  This is often done in game engines for efficiency in the physics/collision subsystem.  To get an AABB for an actor, you can use the following function - this is essentially equivalent to what you did above with `pRenderData->Bounds` but is independent of the actor implementation.

```
FBox GetActorAABB(const AActor& Actor)
{
        FVector ActorOrigin;
        FVector BoxExtent;

        // First argument is bOnlyCollidingComponents - if you want to get the bounds for components that don't have collision enabled then set to false
// Last argument is bIncludeFromChildActors.  Usually this won't do anything but if we've child-ed an actor - like a gun child-ed to a character then we wouldn't want the gun to be part of the bounds so set to false
        Actor.GetActorBounds(true, ActorOrigin, BoxExtent, false);

        return FBox::BuildAABB(ActorOrigin, BoxExtent);
}
```

From code above it looks like you want an oriented bounded box (OBB) since you are applying the transform to it.  Trouble is the AABB Unreal maintains will be "fit" to the world space axes and what you are essentially doing just rotates the center point of the AABB which will not give a "tight fit" for rotation angles far from the world axes.  The following two UE forum posts provide some insight into how you might do this:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/oriented-bounding-box-from-getlocalbounds/241396
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/object-oriented-bounding-box-from-either-aactor-or-mesh/326571/4

If you want a true OBB, `FOrientedBox` is what you need, but the engine lacks documented utilities to do intersection or overlap tests with this structure depending on what you are trying to do, but these things do exist in the engine but you have to hunt through the source code to find them.  In general, the separating axis theorem (SAT) can be used to find collisions between two convex hull shapes, which an OBB is by definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate your own Oriented Bounding Box (OBB) with a center and three extent axes using the following code:

```
// Get the AABB in Local space (aka Object space: such as in the Blueprint viewer). You might want to cache this result as this may be costly. 
const FBox Box = Actor->CalculateComponentsBoundingBoxInLocalSpace();
const FTransform Transform = Actor->GetTransform();

// Get World space Location.
const FVector Center = Transform.TransformPosition(Box.GetCenter());

// And World space extent
const FVector Extent = Box.GetExtent();
const FVector Forward = Transform.TransformVector(FVector::ForwardVector * Extent.X);
const FVector Right = Transform.TransformVector(FVector::RightVector * Extent.Y);
const FVector Up = Transform.TransformVector(FVector::UpVector * Extent.Z);
```

Source: https://www.flogamedev.com/2023/05/18/how-to-calculate-an-actor-oriented-bounding-box-obb-with-unreal-engine/